# Git: merge branch and accept HEAD for all conflicts

Tags: git, version-control

Is it possible to merge a branch into a current branch in git and accept HEAD for all merge conflicts? Basically this says I know what I'm doing and don't care what's in the other branch I'm merging in, accept everything from HEAD of the current branch and do not complain about merge conflicts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-merge.html) for git merge:

```
$ git merge -s ours <branch name>
```